# Как изменить свойства текста в середине тега

Tags: javascript, html

мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, js искал введённое слово по странице и выделял её цветом.
(необращяйте внимание на ошибку если её выдаст)

```js
class Sentenses extends Array{
    constructor(...sentense){
        super(...sentense);
    }
}

function search(){
    let bd_child_nodes = document.body.querySelectorAll('p');
    let input_val = document.getElementById('input');

    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        let bd_arr_x = bd_child_nodes[i].innerText.split(' ');
        let bd_arr = new Sentenses(...bd_arr_x);
        let str = '';
        console.log(bd_arr);
        
        bd_arr.forEach(function(item, x){
                if(item == input_val.value){
                    bd_arr[x] = `<span style='background-color: red;'>${item}</span>`;
                    bd_child_nodes[i].outerHTML.split(' ')[x] = `<span style='background-color: red;'>${item}</span>`;
                    console.log(bd_child_nodes[i].outerHTML.split(' ')[x]);
                }
            }
        )

        bd_arr.forEach(Element => str += `${Element} `);

        bd_child_nodes[i].innerText = str;
        console.log(str);
        console.log('------------------------------------');
    }
}
```

```html
        <input type="text" id="input">
        <button type="submit" onclick="search()">search</button>
        <div>
            <p id="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.Quamineaquefugit tempore ea iste et aut totam dolorum accusantium deleniti, veritatis veniam saepe accusamus perspiciatis nulla, consequuntur cupiditate eum!</p>
        </div>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно что-то такое сделать.. `new RegExp('\\b(${word})\\b', 'g')` ищет слово целиком, например `Lorem ipsum` будет выделен, а `Lorem ips` нет. Если надо что бы искало точные совпадения `(${word})` в этом случае выделит любую совпадающую часть текста например `Lorem ips`.

```js
const content = [...document.body.querySelectorAll('.txt')];
const textContent = content.map(e => e.textContent);

function search() {
  let word = document.getElementById('input').value;
  for (let i = 0; i < textContent.length; i++) {
    content[i].innerHTML = textContent[i].replace(new RegExp(`\\b(${word})\\b` /*`(${word})`*/, 'g'), '<span class="active">$1</span>');
  }
}
```

```css
.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
<button type="submit" onclick="search()">search</button>
<div>
  <p class="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.Quamineaquefugit tempore ea iste et aut totam dolorum accusantium deleniti, veritatis veniam saepe accusamus perspiciatis nulla, consequuntur cupiditate eum!</p>
  <p class="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.Quamineaquefugit tempore ea iste et aut totam dolorum accusantium deleniti, veritatis veniam saepe accusamus perspiciatis nulla, consequuntur cupiditate eum!</p>
</div>
```